# Managing Deadlines and Expectations (What if I complete the work early)

Tags: work-time

My boss has assigned me some work and the deadline is November 15. I completed the work on October 22nd. At present I have told my boss that my first draft is completed but I am still working on it to make it better. I may add few more things to the draft but it is 99% done.

Should I tell my boss that I am done with the assigned work or will it create an expectation that I can always finish the work much early?

Comment: "will it create an expectation that I can always finish the work much early?" why would that be a bad thing?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul A colleague of mine did that and his boss gave him more work to do. The boss was promoted later. My colleague did not get any pay raise or promotion. Eventually, he left the company.

Comment: Actually this happened to me too. My colleague was assigned the same amount of work. I finished early, he did not do anything. My boss gave me his work to complete .. I did my work and then my colleague work.

Comment: @Nobody and my employee who went above and beyond went within a year and few months from making almost nothing to moving to a 1st world country and working for a dream bank they always wanted to. How does that help?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I guess it depends on your luck.

Comment: @johndoe Can you phrase your worries into your question? Right now it verges on being purely opinion based, there's no universal answer, but if your "worry" is that then you will have to work all the hours you do, instead of pretending that stuff takes you longer, it would help to rephrase the question around that, and explains the things you expect to go wrong. As I can see a whole lot of good coming from that, and very little of it is "luck" based. Could include asking for strategies how to turn that into success in your question.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Actually, my personal experience is even worse. I had to work very hard because I got more than I can handle. Then I got heart attack. Took three month disability leave. Got less than average pay raise because of my LOA. So, this is not just luck based opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I think this comes entirely down to a personal choice for you. You have to weigh the morality of not disclosing your lack of work to your boss, the importance of the work you do, the potential gain (if any) you could get from being seen as a hard worker, the potential for getting a more difficult workload by being seen as a fast worker, and your career goals.
Sometimes, depending on the attitude of your boss and company, you will gain a reputation that you are reliable, responsible, and hard working. Other times, you will gain a reputation that you can be taken advantage of and have loads of work dumped on you.

You can somewhat influence the scales by being sure to thoroughly document instances where you complete work early to present during performance reviews to maximize the chance that you are rewarded for your efforts.

I like to be optimistic that hard work will lead to good things, but you know your company best. If you think you will be burning yourself out to line the pockets of already well-paid managers and no gain for yourself, you might also want to then think about why you work for your company. There are plenty of companies where hard work is seen and rewarded.

Answer (score -1):

What made your boss think the deadline was appropriate? Was he advised by someone or did he estimate it himself? Did he have all the information or the necessary expertise to estimate the effort correctly? Is the effort really that big or are you just very fast?

I think an honest approach to this kind of situation is the best. That means both not selling yourself short and not creating excessive expectations. Make it clear which part is due to the misjudged effort and which is your performance.

Be constructive and explain yourself. This can mean, for example, that you explain that you have found a better approach to solving the problem, which has saved you a lot of time. Here you can also emphasize that you excel in finding good and efficient solutions. Hereby you do not show your boss as stupid, if he has given a wrong estimation, but rather emphasize your problem solving abilities in a positive way.